# jquery selector

Tags: jquery

I have a table,m using some function for that table.I want those functions to work only on that table not in any other part.

Is this correct? 
    $(div#xxx) can i use function after this

```
$(div#xxx function({
});
```

Comment: When do you want the function to run?

Comment: You have to provide way more information. What does *I want those functions to work only on that table* mean? And no, the code above is not valid. Functions don't run on their own, you have to call them. And if you only want to use them on a certain table, then do so.

Comment: @kevin:below to it,i have code for selecting through keyboard.the problem is where ever i press enter function is working so,i need to prevent it.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.  Selectors need to be surrounded by quotes, you have to call some jQuery function (or jQuery plugin function) to the jQuery returned by the selector, not as part of the selector, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict the scope of a selector that applies to by giving it as the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) to the jQuery function.  Note that the context must be a document, element, or jQuery (not a raw selector).

Example: attach a click handler to anchors inside table *foo*, but not to any other anchors on the page.

```
$('a',$('table#foo')).click( function() {
   ...
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the ancestor/descendant or parent/child selectors, choose by name, etc.

```
$('table#foo a').click( function() {
   // ancestor descendant
});

$('table#foo > tbody > tr > td > a').click( function() {
  // parent > child (must be direct child)
});

$('a#inside-foo').click( function() {
  // a link by id, presumably inside table foo
});

$('a.inside-foo').click( function() {
  // a link by class, presumably applied only to links inside table foo
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event with any jQuery element, like this:

```
$('div#xxx').event(function(){
});
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-handler-attachment/)

Comment: diEcho:i have wore ('div#xxx'),this means a div tag with id xxx.am,i correct?

Comment: YES...IT MEANS  `select a div which have id=xxx`